# Add type hint to variable mask

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm

I've just started with Python (v.3.7.7) and with PyCharm.

With this code:

```
class NiftiImages:
    def __init__(self):
        self.brain = None
        self.mask = None
```

PyCharm suggest me to "Add type hint to variable 'mask'. And if I hit it, I get this:

```
class NiftiImages:
    mask: None

    def __init__(self):
        self.brain = None
        self.mask = None
```

`brain` and `mask` will always be `Numpy Array`.

What is a type hint for a variable (in this case for a `Numpy Array`)?

Comment: It should just be `self.mask: numpy.array = None`; assuming `import numpy`.